# SQL Server FREETEXT search not returning any results

Tags: sql, search, sql-server-express, freetext

For some reason, I do not get a result on the SQL Server `Freetext` search term with the following code.

Both tables are fulltext indexed (in a catalog), and the query somehow works, but as mentioned, I don't get a result as wished...

```
SELECT [Col8], [Col3]
FROM [Table1]
LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON FREETEXT ([Table1].[Col8] , '[Table2].[Col3]')
```

Table 1:

| ID | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 | 456 | 456 |
| 3 | 789 | 789 | 789 |
| 4 | 0 | anyText | anyText |

Table 2

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 123front | 123behind |
| 2 | 123 | middle123middle | middle123middle |
| 3 | 456 | 456 | 456 |
| 4 | 456 | midle456 |  |
| 5 | 789 | middle789middle | middle7889 |

Result:

| Col8 | Col3 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | NULL |
| 456 | NULL |
| 789 | NULL |
| anyText | NULL |

I want to find any value in `Table2` which matches a value from `Table 1`, e.g., when I search for "123" (`Col8` in `Table1`), then I would like to get as result (from `Col3` in `Table2`):

```
123front    and
middle123middle
```

Comment: What results do you get when you run just this: `SELECT FREETEXT ([Table1].[Col8] , '[Table2].[Col3]')` ?? Is it what you expected? Using `FREETEXT` in a JOIN condition is a bit unusual .... the SQL Server full-text search doesn't operate on *text fragments* (e.g. it's not a 1:1 replacement for `LIKE 'something%'` queries) - it operates on words and stemming of words, and often doesn't return quite what you might be expecting at first....

Comment: With doing that i also only get NULL Values on the Right Column back. I also tried it with the LIKE Term....Wenn ich search for a String LIKE '%123%' then i get the expected results, but when i try to perform a LIKE '%' + [Table2].[Col3] + '%' then it only returns "456" as result, which means that it returns only 100% matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select  *
from [Table1], [Table2]
where [Table2].[Col3] LIKE '%' + [Table1].[Col8] + '%'
```